# JQuery select specific input from multiple in same table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The table cell contains two inputs - a "Numbered Equipment" select and an "Unnumbered Equipment" select, and only one is shown depending on a previous field. Here is that cell:

```
 <td>
                <div class="form-group" id="NumberedNameDiv">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <select id="NumberedName" name="NumberedName" class="form-control select2_field">
                        <option value=""></option>
                      @foreach (App\Models\Equipment::all()->sortby('Name') as $row)
                        <option <?php if ("$row->id" == "$equip1name") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="{{ $row->Name }}">{{ $row->Name }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="UnnumberedNameDiv">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <select id="UnnumberedName" name="UnnumberedName" class="form-control select2_field">
                        <option value=""></option>
                      @foreach (App\Models\Equipmentrates::all()->sortby('EquipmentName') as $row)
                        <option <?php if ("$row->EquipmentName" == "$equip1name") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="{{ $row->EquipmentName }}">{{ $row->EquipmentName }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </td>
```

The cell displays correctly, but my javascript will always select the NumberedName field, regardless of what cell is showing. Here is the javascript:

```
 $("#equipment tr").each(function () {

                var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                var equiptype = row.find('input[name="EquipType"]:checked', '#EquipTypeSelector').val();

                if(equiptype == 'Numbered')
                   {
                        document.getElementById('NumberedNameDiv').style.display ='block';
                        document.getElementById('UnnumberedNameDiv').style.display ='none';

                        equipment = row.find( 'td:eq(1) :selected' ).val();

                                $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                url:  '/equiprates/getvalues',
                                data: {equipment : equipment},

                                success: function(data) {
                                  daily = data.daily;
                                  weekly = data.weekly;
                                  monthly = data.monthly;
                                  duration = row.find( 'td:eq(2) :selected' ).val();
                                  row.find('input[id^="Quantity"]').val(1);

                                      if (duration == 1 || duration == 2 || duration == 3)
                                      {
                                            revenue = daily * duration;
                                            row.find('input[id^="EquipTotal"]').val(revenue);
                                      }
                                      if (duration == 4)
                                      {
                                            revenue = weekly;
                                            row.find('input[id^="EquipTotal"]').val(revenue);
                                      }
                                      if (duration == 12)
                                      {
                                            revenue = monthly;
                                            row.find('input[id^="EquipTotal"]').val(revenue);
                                      }


                                }}) 
                   }

                   if(equiptype == 'Unnumbered')
                   {
                        document.getElementById('NumberedNameDiv').style.display ='none';
                        document.getElementById('UnnumberedNameDiv').style.display ='block';

                        equipment = row.find( 'td:eq(1) :selected' ).val();
                        quantity = row.find('input[id^="Quantity"]').val();

                                $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                url:  '/equiprates/getrecord',
                                data: {ratename : equipment},

                                success: function(data) {
                                  daily = data;
                                  weekly = daily * 4;
                                  monthly = weekly * 3;
                                  duration = $( 'input[id^="Duration"] option:selected' ).val();
                                      if (duration == 1 || duration == 2 || duration == 3)
                                      {
                                            revenue = daily * duration * quantity;
                                            row.find('input[id^="EquipTotal"]').val(revenue);
                                      }
                                      if (duration == 4)
                                      {
                                            revenue = weekly * quantity;
                                            row.find('input[id^="EquipTotal"]').val(revenue);
                                      }
                                      if (duration == 12)
                                      {
                                            revenue = monthly * quantity;
                                            row.find('input[id^="EquipTotal"]').val(revenue);
                                      }


                                }}) 
                   }
            });
```

Is there a better approach to this? Essentially I need it to select the value from UnnumberedName when the equiptype is Unnumbered. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use else instead of if in the following section. Comment back if it still doesnt respond as I work on another approach to your code

remove if

```
if(equiptype == 'Unnumbered'){
}
```

insert else here

```
else(equiptype == 'Unnumbered'){

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I acknowledge that using else is a better approach here but that is definitely not the problem.